# Async Exception Handling in F#

Tags: exception, f#, webclient, f#-async

I am trying to write non-blocking code in F#. I need to download a webpage, but sometime that webpage doesn't exist and an exception is thrown (404 Not Found) by AsyncDownloadString. I tried the code below but it doesn't compile.

How could I handle exception from AsyncDownloadString?

```
let downloadPage(url: System.Uri) = async {
    try
       use webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()
       return! webClient.AsyncDownloadString(url)
    with error -> "Error"
}
```

How am I suppose to handle exception here? If an error is thrown, I simply want to return an empty string or a string with a message in it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add the `return` keyword when you return your error string:

```
let downloadPage(url: System.Uri) = async {
    try
       use webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()
       return! webClient.AsyncDownloadString(url)
    with error -> return "Error"
}
```

IMO a better approach would be to use [`Async.Catch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353899.aspx) instead of returning an error string:

```
let downloadPageImpl (url: System.Uri) = async {
    use webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()
    return! webClient.AsyncDownloadString(url)
}

let downloadPage url =
    Async.Catch (downloadPageImpl url)
```

Comment: Thank you Jack! It works! :) Why do you think Async.Catch is a better approach. I would think that exception handling should be done in downloadPage, no?

Comment: I think `Async.Catch` is better because: (1) it preserves information about the error...there are other reasons an exception might be thrown besides a 404, and having the exception instead of "Error" makes it easier to diagnose the problem; (2) using `Choice<_,_>` allows you to use the type system to enforce the processing paths for both the results and the errors.

Comment: There are circumstances where `Async.Catch` can "leak" an exception (for example when an exception is thrown before the async is created - see: https://gist.github.com/jwosty/c6cb8ae1111ccc5caeb0f6db591d879e).
Using a `try-with` block catches that exception.